# Spam url_alias entries being created - how do I stop them?

Tags: path-aliases, uri, advertising

I'm using Drupal 6 and having trouble with url_alias spam.

Somehow spam entries are showing up in the url_alias table as aliases for valid content.

I thought an administrator or valid user would have to create these.  I don't understand how they're appearing for content that I created.

I appeared to have stopped spam registrations using a combination of Mollom, honey pot and spamicide.  I can't figure out how the url_aliases are appearing.

Can anyone give me a good place to try to start figuring this out?

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Can you tell us exactly how one such spam entry in the `url_alias` table look like? Spam links are usually going to external pages, but a Drupal URL alias will *always* expand to an internal path. Doing what you say the spammers do, don't make sense from the perspective of the spammer.

Answer (score 0):

Who have access to *Administer ➔ Site building ➔ URL aliases* depends on how you've set access to the permissions `administer url aliases` and `create url aliases` under  *Administer ➔ User management ➔ Permissions*.  If you've granted access to the *Anonymous* user role, everybody can do it.  If you've granted access to *Authenticated* user role, a rogue authenticated user can do it.

First, check out these permissions and make sure they are safe.  Leave them unchecked for all roles. Then, only the super admin (user #1) can create aliases using the GUI.

If these setting are secure, and you *still* get unwanted `url_alias` entries created, then some outsider has gained direct access to your database.  That's bad.

Finding the cause of database intrusion is not easy. Possible attack vectors are: A bad module that permits SQL injection, some means outside of Drupal (an inscure *phpMyAdmin* is the most common cause), or (in particular if you're on shared hosting) a host misconfiguration.

However, without having direct access to your site's and its log for forensics, it is impossible to know how an outsider has gotten into your database (if that is indeed the cause).